# channel.recv() behaving differently in my python script and python interactive shell

Tags: python, linux, shell, paramiko, channel

My python script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import paramiko as ssh
import logging
client = ssh.SSHClient()
client.load_system_host_keys()
client.set_missing_host_key_policy(ssh.AutoAddPolicy())
client.connect(TCP_IP, username="root", password=" ")
chan = client.get_transport().open_session()
chan.get_pty()
cmd = "mycommand"
chan.exec_command(cmd)
stdout = chan.recv(BUFFER_SIZE)
print stdout, len(stdout)
```

So now when I ran that script I am getting different outputs.
The original output length be 2058 characters.

But when I ran the scirpt like ./aqu.py , I am just getting 63 characters output and when I need to add lot of recv's to get the whole data.

When I ran those instructions in the python interpreter(entering python command and then entering the commands one by one). I am getting the full output at a single recv.

What maybe the wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You can have this behaviour if your data is not fully buffered. You can use `chan.recv_ready()` to test that. The docs for `recv_ready()` method are [here](http://docs.paramiko.org/en/2.2/api/channel.html#paramiko.channel.Channel.recv_ready)

Edit:
You can do something like this:

```
done = False
while not done:
    result = chan.recv(MAX_BUFF_SIZE)
    # DO something with the result
    done = len(result) == 0
```

Comment: even it has some little data in the buffer, it will return true?
But that is not the behavior that I need. I need when the whole output was buffered.

Comment: Yes, you are right. In this case I recommend you to call `recv` in while loop until it returns 0 bytes received, That should solve your problem.

Comment: Hmmm, it wont return 0. It waits till it gets the data as I am not closing the channel stream. I am just opening it.

Comment: Did you try `recv_exit_status()` before you call `recv()`?

Comment: No, I didn't. Basically the cmd that I am executing never exit itself. It is in the while loop and it's a kind of server. I will create a socket in python and communicate with the server. The cmd outputs a number after executing it, I need to read that one and create a socket with that number

Comment: In this case call `recv` in a while loop until you receive that number. You should somehow parse your result to test if you received the number or not.